# python: is there a way to merge an existing worksheet in my workbook with another sheet from another workbook?

Tags: python, openpyxl, ioerror

I have data in file1.xlsx (sheet 3) and a picture in file2.xlsx (sheet 1).

I want to place that picture next to data in sheet3.

I have tried to use `openpyxl.drawing.image` to insert image but it didn't work:

```
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Then I tried `xlsxwriter` but it doesn't work on an existing workbook, so I end up with 2 workbooks.

Comment: Hey, Anna. The formatting blocks in your question make it hard to understand what is going on. The code you have also doesn't make sense to me. Did you just start python, import openpyxl, and immediately write `openpyxl.drawing.image`? What is the rest of your code here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, Xlsxwriter does not work on 'existing' Excel files. It only creates new files.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to extract the image from the source Excel sheet in `file2.xlsx` and then insert it into `file1.xlsx`. This can be done by using the worksheet `._images` attribute which is a `protected attribute`.
Your code operation may depend on how many images and whether you know the location of them in `file2.xlsx`.
In the code example below we assume 1 image in `file2.xlsx`. The image is placed in `file1.xlsx` at the `destination_cell` location which I have set to 'G1' for this example.
If there is more than 1 image in file2.xlsx you would need to loop through the images in `ws_source._images` and find the one you need

**Note**; if you do not wish to use a `protected attribute` in your code directly you can use the [openpyxl-image-loader](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl-image-loader) wrapper for Openpyxl. It essentially creates a class that does the same thing but you do need to know the location cell of the image. The link gives an example how to utilise.

```py
import openpyxl

# Workbook/worksheet with image
wb_source = openpyxl.load_workbook('file2.xlsx')
ws_source = wb_source['Sheet1']

# Workbook/worksheet where image is to be inserted
wb_destination = openpyxl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
ws_destination = wb_destination['Sheet3']

### Extract image from source and put in destination sheet 
destination_cell = 'G1' # The cell where the image is to be placed
for image in ws_source._images:
    ws_destination.add_image(image, destination_cell)

wb_destination.save(wb_destination)
```